# Sci-fi/fantasy horror movie with four or more man-eating monsters in a cave

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I’m trying to figure out the name of this movie. All I remember is from when I was little. In the movie, there were four or more big hairy like monsters or beasts in a cave and they ate people. I just remember the ending where you see the beasts in the cave.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Not a lot of details here, but _The Descent_ (2005) and _The Descent: Part 2_ (2009) match most of them, except for the "hairy" part.

Comment: Could this have been the 2010 film "Troll Hunter"? There's a scene in a cave with the protagonists hiding from a group of hairy, large-nosed trolls.